# Ability to add tag on SO that 'seems' like a plural but isn't

Tags: feature-request, new-tags-page

I wanted to add a tag 'presenters' but I can't because 'presenter' already exists.

To explain, this is not about a person doing a presentation, it is:

Presenters are used when coding within Ruby on Rails where you use 'presenters' as objects to encapsulate a bunch of functionality.  They are actually called and referred to as 'presenters'

Comment: Prefix that mutha with **ruby-**

Comment: I'd wager if you were referring to a single implementation you wouldn't refer to it in the plural.

Comment: A decent proportion of the existing questions in that tag appear to be about Rails. Is there any reason you can't just go ahead and use it?

Comment: I like ruby-presenters